# Feed a mongodb aggregaion result into a mapReduce

Tags: mongodb

I am doing some analysis in MongoDB. Some of the analysis I can do in the aggregation framework, but there is a step that requires mapReduce. I would like to take the result of the aggregation, which is fast, and pass it directly to the mapReduce, which is a slower step. Is there a way to do this?

I know I can write the results of an aggergation pipeline to a collection using `$out`, but that is very slow (I assume it writes to disk). Speed is important for my use case.

Comment: MapReduce like all mongoDB methods requires input to come from a collection on disk, so I really don't see what the question is about since all data must be in a collection anyway. Secondly it's not really useful to anyone here for you to say "requires mapReduce". Based on what do you make this judgement? If it is your own expert judgement? Then why do you need to ask this question? Either you accept that ouput to a collection is the only way, or rather explain the problem to be solved instead of making assumptions.

Comment: I see...I know it requires a map reduce because the methods available in aggregation framework are not enough for what I want to do.

Comment: Then again, perhaps you should be showing the problem you need to solve as you either get one or the other. 1. Rework the parts you are presently doing in `.aggregate()` so they can be performed in mapReduce. 2. Live with `$out` to another collection to start the mapReduce operation. Of course the third option is to of course fully explain the problem with source data and expected output, as you don't appear to be "expert" enough to be making the call of what you do need if your need to ask this question in the first place. Pretty much what I just said. Maybe this time it will sink in.

Comment: It's self evident that `mapReduce`, which offers a turing complete language at your disposal, has capabilities that `aggregate` does not